# Finding a table in a large SSIS package

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, biml

I am currently working on BI/ETL project in which I have to change the extraction of a dimension table in a very huge SSIS package with lot of dataflow tasks and the data flow tasks names are not in accordance with table name. Is there a way to search for the table in that SSIS package to find its particular data flow task?

Comment: You can check [SSISDB].[catalog].[packages] and look at packages XML as indicated in this link : https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/211796/finding-table-name-referfences-in-ssis-packages

Comment: Are you Biml'ing or just tagging things to get eyeballs?